# regex pattern for URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Im using the following URL regex pattern for URL validation.

```
/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
```

But i need to exclude `.com`
 ie `http://google/` should work.

What change needs to be done for this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Put everything from the first `\.` onwards in parentheses and follow with a question mark. And then go back and fix your existing pattern, which currently accepts things like `:::::.zz` and `??.aa` as valid URLs.

Comment: @jfriend00 `www.google.com` is matching with the regex pattern.But `http://google/` shows does not match error. so im looking for a regex pattern which matches with the URL `http://google/`

Comment: I'd suggest you use the Edit button to edit your question so others can follow what you're trying to do.  Add some examples of URLs that you want to pass and not pass and which ones you need help with solving.

Comment: @nnnn can you pls provide an example?

Comment: @user833985 Would you please provide more samples of url that to be matched ?

Comment: `http://abc/dd/cccc/` should match. i just need to exclude the matching of `.com` from the pattern i provided.

Answer (score 3):

You better user this length expression from jquery.validate.js extension. This is well tested and support multilingual urls. **Don't afraid of unicode and hexadecimal expression inside the expression**. Its only to support multilingual urls. Refer [this (Unicode Characters)](http://web.archive.org/web/20101104085449/http://hamstersoup.com/javascript/regexp_character_class_tester.html)  to understand what following unicode means

```
/^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i
```

Your above expression has lots of flaw like last part of your expression `\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?` itself match the whole url and does not have any effect of the previous expression

Answer (score 2):

assuming you want everything including urls without the .com in it.

```
/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}

(?:\.[a-z]{2,4})? // (?:) match group this is where the .com is captured
                  // ? quantifier 0 to 1 times

\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b4BnU/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply take this section: `\.[a-z]{2,4}` and replace it with `(\.[a-z]{2,4})?`.

The full regex:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}(\.[a-z]{2,4})?\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?
```

And a [`demo`](http://regex101.com/r/wF2eJ2).

Effectively what we're doing here is making the `.xxxx` optional, by wrapping it in `()` and using the `?` to denote a non-greedy state.

This will match both:

```
http://www.google.com/
```

and

```
http://localhost/
```

**Caveat:** this isn't the most efficient expression to accomplish what you want, but it is simply the smallest required adjustment needed to accomplish what you want.